# Syncing an object between two projects on different devices over the network

Tags: c#, networking, synchronization

I have two projects communicating over a wireless network.  I have communication working fine between the two.

I would like to maintain two identical copies of some objects on both programs.  The objects needn't be equal (in a reference sense), however the objects must show the same data when viewed.

Is there an existing technology to do this, or am I going to have to roll my own...?

Comment: This is a hard to implement Pattern, but it can be done. However I think you should probably rethink the issue to avoid needing this Object in the first place. However if you can't one Object needs to be the Master and the rest Ghosts of that object.

Comment: I have two projects, one on the desktop, one on a mobile device.  I'd like to share a list of contacts between the two.  Ideally, I'd like to make it so that if I make a change to a contact on the mobile device, it sends the change to the desktop, which raises a change event for the desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

If you can communicate between the two processes, then you should be able serialize the changes in any object, and notify the other process of the change.  One thing I'd be worried about is what happens if the two objects change simultaneously - you'd have two stale objects and neither of them is valid.

Have a look at this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx) tutorial for more information on serialization.